# How to do a hibernate saving without duplicate records in a different table

Tags: java, hibernate

Can someone help on the following scenario, please? Let say I have table 1

```
|----------------|--------------|------------|--------|
|      Salesman  |     Product  |     Year   |  Sold  |
|----------------|--------------|------------|--------|
|      John      |     prod1    |    2015    | 2000   |
|----------------|--------------|------------|--------|
|      John      |     prod1    |    2016    | 2000   |
|----------------|--------------|------------|--------|
|      John      |     prod2    |    2015    | 2000   |
|----------------|--------------|------------|--------|
|      John      |     prod2    |    2016    | 2000   |
|----------------|--------------|------------|--------|
|      Tracy     |     prod1    |    2015    | 2000   |
|----------------|--------------|------------|--------|
|      Tracy     |     prod1    |    2016    | 2000   |
|----------------|--------------|------------|--------|
|      Tracy     |     prod2    |    2015    | 2000   |
|----------------|--------------|------------|--------|
|      Tracy     |     prod2    |    2016    | 2000   |
|----------------|--------------|------------|--------|
```

As you can see in table 1, Salesman, Product are not unique key. However, now I want to do a saving to table 2 with some detailed info for Salesman and Product combination. In other words, I want the Salesman and product is unique in table 2.

```
    |----------------|--------------|--------|
    |      Salesman  |     Product  |priority|
    |----------------|--------------|--------|
    |      John      |     prod1    | true   |
    |----------------|--------------|--------|
    |      John      |     prod2    | false  |
    |----------------|--------------|--------|
    |      Tracy     |     prod1    | true   |
    |----------------|--------------|--------|
    |      Tracy     |     prod2    | true   |
    |----------------|--------------|--------|
```

Is there anyway I can use the following entity for hibernate.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table1")
public class EntityTable1() {
    private String salesman;
    private String product;
    private int year;
    private int sold;
    private List<EntityTable2> entityTable2;

    ....
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table2")
public class EntityTable2() {
    private String salesman;
    private String product;
    private boolean priorityTarget;

    ....
}
```

Is there anyway, when I save EntityTable1 objects, I save EntityTable2 cascade and also make sure table2 doesn't have duplicate rows? I understand there will be other ways to change the entity or DB design. However, since I am working on a project that have been built and used by other team, I cannot simply change table 1 schema. But I can do whatever for table 2. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It very much depends on what you want to be unique in EntityTable2. Do you want the combination of all your fields to be unique? In that case you would need something like this:

```
@Table(
   name = "table2", 
   uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"salesman", "product", "priorityTarget"})}
)
```

Do you want the individual fields to be unique? Then you would want something like this:

```
@Table(
        name = "table2",
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "salesman"),
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "product"),
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "priorityTarget")
        }
)
```

And of course you can mix and match the above.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this using Hibernate Interceptor. You can save the objects of table2 in the onSave event of table1.

For uniqueness you will need to check if the record exists, if it exists, update the same record else create a new one.